# Function $f(t)=\frac{t}{2\epsilon}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2\epsilon}\right)$ at $t=0$

Tags: functions, distribution-theory

My professor said that the function (rect is the [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)):

$$f(t)=\frac{t}{2\epsilon}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2\epsilon}\right)$$

at $t=0$ is always $0$ for each value of $\epsilon$. Why? If $\epsilon=0$, it will be:

$$f(0)=\frac00\operatorname{rect}(0/0)$$

which is an indeterminate form (maybe $\operatorname{rect}(0/0)=\infty$).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's a common convention that $\varepsilon>0$. That is probably the cause of this confusion.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen What you say is true, but maybe the OP is interested in the limit $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Yes at the beginning $\epsilon>0$, but after he did the limit.

Comment: The function does converge to zero, in the sense of distributions, as $\varepsilon\to0$. Could that be the intended meaning?

Comment: Hi @HaraldHanche-Olsen yes, the context is the field of the distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add a subscript $\varepsilon$ to your function $f$.

For any test function $\varphi$, you get
$$ \langle \varphi,f_\varepsilon\rangle
 = \int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\frac{t}{2\varepsilon}\varphi(t)\,dt, $$
and taking absolute values,
$$ \lvert\langle \varphi,f_\varepsilon\rangle\rvert
 \le\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\frac12\lvert\varphi(t)\rvert\,dt
 \to0\quad\text{as $\varepsilon\to0$},
$$
so that $f_\varepsilon\to0$ in the sense of distributions as $\varepsilon\to0$.

Of course, distributions don't have pointwise values, so it may seem senseless to talk about the value at $t=0$ here, but one can make an exception for distributions arising from continuous functions – in this case, the constant zero.